# get an error when create instance in c++

Tags: c++, instance

Header file :

```
class FakeMas
{
   FakeMas();
   ~FakeMas();
}
```

CPP file:

```
FakeMas::FakeMas(){........}
FakeMas::~FakeMas(){}
```

I write a cpp file to test the FakeMas:

```
class FakeMasTest{
    void test() 
    {
        FakeMas fakemas;            
        fakemas.start();
    }
}
```

the classes in the project called "zinc.testwebserver"

If I build it it says

```
FakeMasTest.cpp:29: undefined reference to `zinc::testwebserver::FakeMas::FakeMas()'"
```

If I change the test to:

```
FakeMas::FakeMas * fakemas = new FakeMas::FakeMas();
```

it says

```
error: ‘fakemas’ was not declared in this scope
```

If I change the test to:

```
FakeMas * fakemas = new FakeMas();
```

it says

```
undefined reference to `zinc::testwebserver::FakeMas::FakeMas()'
```

I really do not know how to do it...

get any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Apart from not linking your implementation properly, just use `FakeMas fakeMas;`.

Comment: Please show your compile and link command lines, or makefile if you have one.

Comment: Do you include header with `FakeMas` into cpp file with `FakeMasTest`?

Comment: @chris As I state above, if I use FakeMas fakemas, it will say "undefined reference to `zinc::testwebserver::FakeMas::FakeMas()'"

Comment: @user1853170, Undefined reference means it can't find the definition, which most likely means you're not linking the cpp containing the definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a link error: the object code from `FakeMas.cpp` is not being linked with the object code from `FakeMasTest.cpp`

(these would be `FakeMas.o` and `FakeMasTest.o` on some platforms, `.obj` on others - you haven't specified yours).

So, your code *compiles*, but cannot be formed into an executable. The solution depends on your build system (which again you haven't specified), but is essentially to tell it that your executable depends on, and should contain, both object files.

---

The *unrelated* error you got is because this isn't valid:

```
FakeMas::FakeMas * fakemas = new FakeMas::FakeMas();
```

it should be:

```
FakeMas * fakemas = new FakeMas();
```

(and then you'll be back to the same link error).

---

From your Makefile:

```
CppUnit_Tests = fakemastest
TESTS = $(CppUnit_Tests)
testdir = $(prefix)/tests/@PACKAGE@/test
test_PROGRAMS = $(CppUnit_Tests)

fakemastest_SOURCES = FakeMasTest.cpp
```

you're telling Make that the executable `fakemastest` depends *only* on `FakeMasTest.cpp`. Tell it about `FakeMas.cpp` as well, by changing the last line:

```
fakemastest_SOURCES = FakeMasTest.cpp FakeMas.cpp
```

(this is making certain assumptions about your build rules, which aren't shown, but it's a sensible place to start).

Comment: Just edit this into the question, it'll be easier than a chain of one-line comments

Comment: Yes, as I've edited into my answer. You can delete the one-line comments too, btw.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that compiler cannot find the declaration of `FakeMas`. Either you didn't add

```
#include "FakeMas.h"
```

or you need to specify correct namespace:

```
using namespace namespace_with_FakeMas;
```

Compiler message shows that compiler is looking for a class declaration in namespace `zinc::testwebserver`. It seems that this is not the same namespace where `FakeMas` was declared.

Comment: in those three files(FakeMas.h, FakeMas.cpp, FakeMasTest.cpp) I all start with "NS_ZINC_TESTWEBSERVER_OPEN"

Comment: "NS_ZINC_TESTWEBSERVER" is namespace